# PHP Custom two way encryption and decryption , what i am doing wrong?

Tags: php, encryption, hash, cryptography

i am trying to obfuscate/encrypt a number into string and then again want to de-ubfuscate/decrypt that string to get a number.

i cant use base64 or any other public available algorithmbs as the generated hash is gonna be personal and specific to each user and cant be shared with other users, its for creating personal urls which will contains the personal hash.

basically i want to generate hash from the userid as userid is unique and doesnt changes.

so far i have created custom function to encrypt the userid and get hash from it.

```
<?php
$base_encryption_array = array(
'0'=>'b76',
'1'=>'d75',
'2'=>'f74',
'3'=>'h73',
'4'=>'j72',
'5'=>'l71',
'6'=>'n70',
'7'=>'p69',
'8'=>'r68',
'9'=>'t67',
'a'=>'v66',
'b'=>'x65',
'c'=>'z64',
'd'=>'a63',
'e'=>'d62',
'f'=>'e61',
'g'=>'h60',
'h'=>'i59',
'i'=>'j58',
'j'=>'g57',
'k'=>'f56',
'l'=>'c55',
'm'=>'b54',
'n'=>'y53',
'o'=>'w52',
'p'=>'u51',
'q'=>'s50',
'r'=>'q49',
's'=>'o48',
't'=>'m47',
'u'=>'k46',
'v'=>'i45',
'w'=>'g44',
'x'=>'e43',
'y'=>'c42',
'z'=>'a41'
);

function my_custom_encode($string){
global $base_encryption_array ;
$string = (string)$string;
$length = strlen($string);
$hash = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
        if(isset($string[$i])){
            $hash .= $base_encryption_array[$string[$i]];
        }
    }
return $hash;
}


function my_custom_decode($hash){
global $base_encryption_array ;
/* this makes keys as values and values as keys */
$base_encryption_array = array_flip($base_encryption_array);

$hash = (string)$hash;
$length = strlen($hash);
$string = '';

    for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i=$i+3) {
        if(isset($hash[$i]) && isset($hash[$i+1]) && isset($hash[$i+2]) && isset($base_encryption_array[$hash[$i].$hash[$i+1].$hash[$i+2]])){
            $string .= $base_encryption_array[$hash[$i].$hash[$i+1].$hash[$i+2]];
        }
    }
return $string;
}?>
```

so far everything works fine.
encryption works fine for multiple levels / iterations.

bu the decryption of multiple iterated hash doesn't work, it only works for single encrypted value and not for 2 times encrypted values.

for eg.
my php function to create multiple iterated hash from userid, i am using 2 times encryption like this.

```
<?php
function userid_to_hash($userid){
    for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
        $userid = my_custom_encode($userid);
    }

/* it returns hash*/
return $userid;
}?>
```

and my multiple iterations decode function

---

lets say userid = 41;

so when i do this

```
<?php
$userid = 41;
echo userid_to_hash($userid)."<br>";
?>
```

i get output

**g57p69f74a63p69l71**

but when i want to decrypt the hash and get userid i get blank space. like this

```
<?php
$hash = 'g57p69f74a63p69l71';
echo hash_to_userid($hash);
?>
```

i get blank white page . but if i set the $hash to single level decryption like this and use the **custom function my_custom_decode** then it works fine for single iteration.

```
<?php
$hash = 't67';
echo my_custom_decode($hash);
?>
```

gives correct output .
**9**

Comment: You're for loop in my_custom_decode looks like you're running the risk of indexing out of bounds. If you're getting a blank white page, post the exception thrown in the logs. My guess is "Out of Bounds Exception". If your string length isn't modulo 3 == 0 then you're going to hit that during one of your $hash[$i+n] calls.

Comment: I don't think you understand how EASY it would be for someone to decrypt this "encryption". It is completely insecure. You are simply doing a character translation. You could likely rewrite your entire function using [strtr](http://www.php.net/strtr) which does exactly what your loop/concat is doing..

Comment: *"i get blank white page"* - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: PHP has a built in function [strtr](http://www.php.net/strtr) that does exactly what your encrypt/decrypt function does. Your encrypt function can be called like `strtr($string, $base_encryption_array);` and decrypt would be `strtr($encrypted, array_flip($base_encryption_array));`

Comment: Why are you writing your own encryption when there are well vetted secure algorithm such as AES available? The chances of it being even minimally secure are remote to nonexistent. Also hashes are not encryption, they are one-way functions. In your case consider using HMAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using an encryption library.

The answer to your question is because you are using global variable.

It is really a bad practice to do so :

`global $base_encryption_array ;
/* this makes keys as values and values as keys */
$base_encryption_array = array_flip($base_encryption_array);`

You keep flipping the array, in your 2nd loop (when you try to decode), it cant find anymore the key, because you flipped it twice.

The ugly quick fix, just rename the array variable inside the my_custom_decode.

Answer (score 23):

> "PHP Custom two way encryption and decryption",
>   **what i am doing wrong?**

You're trying to write custom encryption.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Answer (score 7):

> i cant use base64 or any other public available algorithmbs as the generated hash is gonna be personal and specific to each user and cant be shared with other users, its for creating personal urls which will contains the personal hash.

You're missing the point of encryption:

- Algorithms should be public and well-studied.
- The *keys* should be kept secret.

To that effect: [Recommended PHP cryptography libraries](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide).

EDIT 2017-10-17:

> its for creating personal urls which will contains the personal hash.

Sorry, I missed this part of your question in my initial answer, somehow.

Encryption isn't even the right tool for the job of [obfuscating database IDs from GET requests](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php). You want to use a randomly generated token / separate lookup instead.

Comment: Many of those libraries are overkill and too CPU heavy for some tasks. I want to process a page of 100 records to obfuscate download links. Obviously, base64 is not enough (not even with a salt because you still can see the ID in clear text when decoded), Blowfish is an overkill, and hashing does not work because I need two-way encryption. So, what would be the fastest way to create simple and CPU-friendly obfuscation solution?  Is there a built-in simple two way encryption in PHP? If not, then custom character dictionary seems ok, if done right.

Comment: Please see: [The guide to URL parameter encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php) which includes database ID obfuscation.

Comment: Furthermore: "Obviously, base64 is not enough (not even with a salt because you still can see the ID in clear text when decoded)" -- Please read: [You Wouldn't Base64 a Password](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). Base64 isn't even encryption, it's encoding.

Comment: Yes, a dedicated database column seems the cleanest solution, if developing a system where it is allowed to change database schema. But with distributed legacy systems sometimes it is not possible, and then there is still a need for something less heavy than encryption and more protected than simple hash or encoding. Encoding is just to make the data more URL friendly or to make it less obvious. Anyway, it would be nice to have something built-in for PHP. Even XOR with custom key might be enough.

Comment: "there is still a need for something less heavy than encryption" Citation needed. Benchmark libsodium's `crypto_secretbox()` and come back to me with any evidence a meaningful performance loss.

"Even XOR with custom key might be enough." No, it wouldn't.

Comment: @JustAMartin CPU usage for encryption hasn't been a serious concern for the past decade or so. Hardware acceleration exists nowadays, and implementations are only getting more efficient. Aside from that, there's no "done right" when it concerns custom obfuscation schemes; using obfuscation here is the wrong thing to do *by definition*, no matter what your implementation looks like.